# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: database

i got this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How can i fix the database with the correct password

Comment: This is a duplicate question - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/access-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-database this is a general MySQL connection issue and is highly documented.

Answer (score 3):

Goto magento dir `/app/etc/` and open `local.xml.` here check `database username ,database name,database user password`.

```
<password><![CDATA[MYdbPASSWORD]]></password>
```

just change `MYdbPASSWORD` to your password

Under `CDATA[] ,you need to put password`
Also you need check `database username ,database name,database user password`.

If you use Window system  then most of case password is require field.

Answer (score 2):

Using password:NO means you are trying to connect to mysql without password, so unless your database doesn't have a password, you have to insert it in app/etc/local.xml